# Libgdx, viewport in actor

Tags: libgdx, viewport, actor

Is it possible to put viewport inside a custom actor, so that viewport width and height will be actor's width and height, and rendering will start from actor position, no from (0,0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stage` is a 2D scene graph. It has a hierarchical structure, which means that `Actor`s added to a `Group` should already be rendered only inside that given `Group`. Moving the Group will also move all children inside. Via `clipBegin()` and `clipEnd` you can also "cut off" everything that's not inside the actor, which is kind of what a `Viewport` does as well, when setting the `glViewport`.

So probably you won't need an extra Viewport for whatever you are trying to do. If you still think you need one, you can create an `ActorViewport extends Viewport` which gets an `Actor` field. You would have to override the `apply(boolean)` method and synchronize the worldWidth, worldHeight, screenX, screenY, screenWidth and screenHeight variables to match the `Actor`. Remember that you will have to update the viewport everytime the actor changes, which is in every frame in the worst case.

Comment: To support zooming in and out of an actor (for example if my world map is of type Image) could this be accomplished without using an actor viewport?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to noone solution was very simple:

```
public class ActorViewport extends Viewport
{
     private Actor m_actor;

     public ActorViewport(Actor actor, int worldWidth, int worldHeight, Camera camera)
     {
          m_actor = actor;
          setWorldSize(worldWidth, worldHeight);
          setCamera(camera);
     }

     @Override
     public void update(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, boolean centerCamera)
     {
          setScreenPosition((int)m_actor.getX(), (int)m_actor.getY());
          setScreenSize((int)m_actor.getWidth(), (int)m_actor.getHeight());
     }
}
```